# Terraform user_data not executing the bash script on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to execute a bash script using `terraform user_data.`

```
resource "aws_instance" "myec2vm" {
  ami = "ami-069d73f3235b535bd"
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  key_name = var.already_created_key_pair
  user_data = file("${path.module}/install.sh")
  tags = {
    "Name": "EC2Demo"
  }
}
```

The `bash script` and `terraform manifest` are directly under the same root directory.

However, the script `install.sh` is not getting executed.

Comment: Have you checked the logs? I think you can take a look at `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` and `/var/log/cloud-init.log`.

Comment: Thanks. After looking into the logs I have found the error `Exec format error. Missing #! in script?`
I added shebang but it was not on the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per information provided in the question, its not possible to propose 100% correct answer but let me give you some hints:

1. Make sure your script starts with valid shebang. for example: `#!/bin/bash`. More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts)
2. If both manifest and script files are under same directory then you can skip `${path.module}` and reference script directly using `user_data = file("install.sh")`

If it still doesn’t work then kindly provide more information like bash script, folder structure and command used to apply tf changes.

Comment: I also ran into this and had my shebang on the second line inadvertently.